# Add multiple records in ADO .Net without an iterator

Tags: vb6, ado.net

I am working on a legacy ADO .Net code in VB6. The current code iterates through a dictionary and creates a new record for the RecordSet, rs,  for each key in the dictionary. This is the current code (rs is a record set):

```
For Each k In dictionary.Keys

    rs.AddNew
    rs(field1) = value1
    rs(field2) = dictionary(k)
    rs.Update
Next
```

I want to optimize the above code and add the records in a batch. Something like this:

```
Dim fieldOne As New Collection

Dim fieldTwo As New Collection

Dim valueOne As New Collection

Dim valueTwo As New Collection

For Each k In dictionary.Keys   

    fieldOne.Add (field1)
    fieldTwo.Add (field2)
    valueOne.Add (value1)
    valueTwo.Add (dictionary(k))

Next

rs.AddNew Array(fieldOne, fieldTwo), Array(valueOne, valueTwo)

rs.UpdateBatch
```

Is it possible to create multiple records in one Add statement in ADO .Net RecordSet? How can I bypass the iterator in such a situation, where not only I have multiple fields, but the fields have multiple values as well?

Comment: This will not work.  Instead, try moving the rs.Update from inside the loop to after the loop.  This should allow for batch updating.

Comment: Something wrong here.  VB6 and ADO.Net don't mix well.  What's really involved?  It looks like ADO, not ADO.Net.